# Integrate or hide Minimize/Restore/Close buttons on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to hide or integrate the Minimize/Restore/Close to other bar on Internet Explorer 11, so that they don't occupy a useless bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing F11 (while ie is running)for both on and off for full screen viewing.  You can mouse up to the top to bring the smaller menu bar back after it disappears.